# Pulling data from Google Chat into Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-chat

I'm trying to pull data from google chat into a spreadsheet but I only need to pull the messages from one Space. I found a script to pull all chat messages but how can I specify which Space to pull from?

```
function getChats() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Date");
  sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue("Subject");
  sheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue("Body");
  var row = 2;
  
  var chats = GmailApp.getChatThreads();
  var chat_count = chats.length;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < chat_count; i++) {
   var count = chats[i].getMessageCount();
   var messages = chats[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      var chat_date = messages[j].getDate();
      var subject = messages[j].getSubject();
      var body = messages[j].getBody();
      sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(chat_date);
      sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(subject);
      sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(body);
      row++;
    }
    
  }
  Browser.msgBox("All done!");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212971/get-google-chat-threads-from-today-to-google-sheet

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces

Comment: @Cooper Is there a way to add the JSON representation (developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces) into the existing JSON script?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would you wish to add data to the manifest?

Comment: I reviewed the links you sent but I just have no idea where I would put it. Would it go in the manifest or the function.

Comment: Your manifest is used to configure the setup for your projects google apps script.  I would leave it alone.  It's your data where do you want to put it?